# Default rabbitmq exchange type

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

As per my understanding `RabbitMQ` server by default creates exchange of type `Direct` i.e If I create exchange without providing any type it will create exchange of type Direct.
Is there any way by which I can change default behavior i.e default exchange type as `fanout` instead of `Direct` i.e if exchange type is missing then exchange should be of type `Fanout` not`Direct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't configurable, but there is a default fanout exchange that is also created.